# How do i store the entire text as words

Tags: android

Suppose I've retrieved a text from EditText and stored it in a string:

```
String str = "Hello, I am new to Android.
```

Now i want to store the text in an array this way:

```
array={"Hello,","I","am","new","to","Android."};
```

Comment: spit string using  " "

Comment: Simply use .splt(), `String[] split = str.split(" ");`

Answer (score 3):

Split the string based on space and store it in an array. Take a look

```
str = "Hello, I am new to Android";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You split the string on the space character.

```
String[] array = str.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

use below line of code 
String []array = str.split(" ");

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "Hello, I am new to Android";
String[] parts = string.split(",");
String part1 = parts[0]; // Hello
String part2 = parts[1]; // I am new to Android

String[] partss = part2.split(" ");
String part11 = parts[0]; // I
String part22 = parts[1]; // am 
.....
```